# How does one extract the work characterized by the Helmholtz energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws

From Wikipedia:

> Helmholtz free energy is a thermodynamic potential that measures the
>   useful work obtainable from a closed thermodynamic system at a
>   constant temperature and volume (isothermal, isochoric)

I struggle to understand the Helmholtz more than the Gibbs because of the isochoric nature of its definition. Given that the work extractable by a process on a gas is `p * dV`, how can one characterize *any* "useful work obtainable from from a closed thermodynamic system at constant ... volume"?

Comment: $p_{ext} dV$ refers to pressure-volume work only.  But many other types of work are also possible, e.g., electrical work.

Answer (score 1):

Not all work is *pV work* (also called expansion work and a type of mechanical work). non-pV work is possible, e.g. chemical, surface, electrical, magnetic, gravitational (admittedly restricting the system to a gas requires a little creativity in envisioning how such non-pV work might come about).

The first law of thermodynamics can be written generally as $$\begin{align}dU&=dq+dw \\ &=dq+dw_{pV}+dw_{non-pV}\\ &=dq_{rev}-pdV+dw_{non-pV,rev}\end{align}$$
In the last equation the work is performed reversibly, there is mechanical balance between the system and surroundings ($p=p_{ext})$.
The transform to generate the enthalpy function H only alters the contribution  of the expansion work to the internal energy U:

$$\begin{align}dH&=dU+d(pV) \\ &=dq_{rev} + Vdp+dw_{non-pV}\end{align}$$

or for an isobaric ($dp=0$) closed process

$$dH = dq_{rev} + dw_{non-pV}$$

Therefore the non-pV contribution to the total work is retained in the enthalpy change for an *isobaric* process (not isochoric as I had previously bizarrely written).

Similarly, we can evaluate the differential change in the Helmholtz function A as

$$\begin{align}dA&=dU-d(TS) \\ &=  -pdV+dw_{non-pV} -SdT\end{align}$$

It follows that for an isothermal (constant T, $dT=0$) and isochoric (constant V, $dV=0$) process,

$$dA=  dw_{non-pV} $$

Therefore the non-pV contribution to the total work is retained in the Helmholtz free energy change for an *isochoric* and *isothermal* process. In fact, under these conditions the Helmholtz function is equal to this work.